# Open Cart - Receiving radio value at checkout page

Tags: php, forms, radio-button, opencart

I need help to create a radio box during the checkout.
I have no idea how to have the result of the radio box send along with my other information in the checkout page such as billing address and many more.

this is what i do ,

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_address" value="existing" id="shipping-address-existing" checked="checked" class="radio inline" />
<b><?php echo $text_delivery2; ?></b>

<input type="radio" name="shipping_address" value="existing" id="shipping-address-existing" checked="checked" class="radio inline" />
<b><?php echo $text_delivery3; ?></b>
</label>
```

but there is nothing shown. 
thanks

Comment: What's not being shown, the PHP inside the <b> tags, and do you get any errors?

Comment: What file are you editing in open cart to add these inputs?

Comment: check your CSS file, in such cases opencart is showing visibilty:hidden; or there must be color conflict with background.

Answer (score 1):

First be specic on question because the checkout page contains list of conditions along with various section (login,register,payment address, payment method, shipping address, shipping method, quick confirm etc)

There are list of action and their regarding template, So you need to change in the regarding file, Suppose you are adding radio button on billing address

Find regarding template file and add radio

```
//template>checkout>payment_address.tpl 
<input type="radio" name="shipping_address" value="existing1" id="shipping-address-existing" checked="checked" class="radio inline" />
<b><?php echo 'Delivery2'; ?></b>

<input type="radio" name="shipping_address" value="existing2" id="shipping-address-existing" checked="checked" class="radio inline" />
<b><?php echo 'Delivery3'; ?></b>
</label>
```

Now in checkout page you can see your radio buttons, It uses the ajax method to parse data to function

```
//in line 350 of template>checkout>checkout.tpl
```

you can see a ajax function function

```
$('#button-payment-address').live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address/validate',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#payment-address input[type=\'text\'], #payment-address input[type=\'password\'], #payment-address input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #payment-address input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #payment-address input[type=\'hidden\'], #payment-address select'),
        dataType: 'json',
```

Here the url repreesnts the controller function

```
// controller>checkout>payment_address.php and function is validate()
```

Here you can fetch your radio value `$_POST['shipping_address']` because in ajax 
we have defined `type: 'post'`

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to put in delivery method in checkout. my theme is sellegance. where should i put the codes in ? THANKS btw !!!!

Comment: And this is my code, the previous was wrong.
`code`
<label class="inline-radio"><input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="delivery" id="delivery" checked/> Ship only </label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label class="inline-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="delivery2" id="delivery2"/> Ship ready</label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label class="inline-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="delivery3" id="delivery3" /> Consult </label>

Comment: I don't get it at the part ajax function, can you further explain, please?

Comment: in the ajax you can see the url:index.php?route=checkout/payment_address/validate

it means the data is passed to that url so you need to perform whatever you want in that target page controller>checkout>payment_address.php and function is validate() whare you can fetch data from post method $_POST['shipping_address']