# Opencart - I want to create a set of radio button in checkout page

Tags: php, radio-button, smarty, opencart

I want to create a set of radio button in checkout page at my delivery method - sellegance theme.

My code is appearing in the delivery method section. But the problem is I don't know how to receive the value from the radio button. I want the value to be sent along with other information in the checkout page to my email.

I put the code in /public_html/catalog/view/theme/sellegance/template/checkout/shipping_method.tpl

```
<label class="inline-radio"><input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="delivery" id="delivery" checked/> Ship only </label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <label class="inline-radio"> <input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="delivery2" id="delivery2"/> Ship ready</label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <label class="inline-radio"> <input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="delivery3" id="delivery3" /> Consult </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code is a part of a form with a POST method, you need to refer to value of `$_POST['delivery_method']`.

You have to modify the appropriate controller, which handles the POST data. It is located at `catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_method.php`. The method that you are looking of is probably `validate()` at around line *88*.

Take a look at the answer of *Stefan Koenen* to another question:
[Php - testing if a radio button is selected and get the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416099/php-testing-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-and-get-the-value)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the similar link, simply you can follow them.

[Open Cart - Receiving radio value at checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730799/open-cart-receiving-radio-value-at-checkout-page/20739517#20739517)

And for Email you need to modify values at

```
catalog>model>checkout>order::confirm()
```

Comment: I don't get it with the link. Is that one for shipping_method.tpl ?
And you want me to modify values at catalog>model>checkout>order::confirm() , where should I add in value ?

Comment: Actually this is just a reference link showing how you can modify on checkout page, above link shows adding radio on delivery address.

And as you asked to send additional information to email so 
catalog>model>checkout>order::confirm() contains the mail function that helps to send email after order checkout confirmed

Answer (score 0):

```
  Here is full solution....
  Open file..
        /*** TIME SLOT OPENCART CODING ***/

        C:\wamp\www\OC\catalog\controller\checkout\shipping_method.php

        1)
        Find :- 
        $this->session->data['comment'] = strip_tags($this->request->post['comment']);

        After that copy and paste :-
        $this->session->data['shipping_timeslot'] = $this->request->post['shipping_timeslot'];
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        2)
        Find :- 
        $this->data['text_shipping_method'] = $this->language->get('text_shipping_method');

        After that copy and paste :-
        $this->data['text_shipping_timeslot'] = $this->language->get('text_shipping_timeslot');
        $this->data['ship_slot_one'] = $this->language->get('ship_slot_one');
        $this->data['ship_slot_two'] = $this->language->get('ship_slot_two');
        $this->data['ship_slot_three'] = $this->language->get('ship_slot_three');
        $this->data['ship_slot_four'] = $this->language->get('ship_slot_four');
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        3)
        Find :- 
        if (isset($this->session->data['comment'])) {
        $this->data['comment'] = $this->session->data['comment'];
        } else {
        $this->data['comment'] = '';
        }

        After that copy and paste :-
        if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_timeslot'])) {
        $this->data['shipping_timeslot'] = $this->session->data['shipping_timeslot'];
        } else {
        $this->data['shipping_timeslot'] = '';
        }
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        C:\wamp\www\OC\catalog\model\checkout\order.php

        1)
        Find :-
        commission = '" . (float)$data['commission'] . "'

        After that copy and paste :-
        shipping_time_slot = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_timeslot']) . "',

        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        C:\wamp\www\OC\catalog\language\english\checkout\checkout.php

        1)
        Find :-
        $_['text_length']

        After that copy and paste :-
        $_['text_shipping_timeslot']           = 'Please select the preferred shipping time slot.';
        $_['ship_slot_one']           = 'Morning';
        $_['ship_slot_two']           = 'Afternoon';
        $_['ship_slot_three']           = 'Evening';
        $_['ship_slot_four']           = 'Night';

        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        C:\wamp\www\OC\catalog\view\theme\vitalia\template\checkout\shipping_method.tpl

        1)
        Find :-
        <p><?php echo $text_shipping_method; ?></p>

        Above that copy and paste :-
        <p><?php echo $text_shipping_timeslot; ?></p>
        <table class="radio">

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><b><?php echo "Delivery time slot"; ?></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="highlight">
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="shipping_timeslot" value="<?php echo $ship_slot_one; ?>" id="morning" checked="checked"/><?php echo $ship_slot_one; ?></br>
                    <input type="radio" name="shipping_timeslot" value="<?php echo $ship_slot_two; ?>" id="afternoon"/><?php echo $ship_slot_two; ?></br>
                    <input type="radio" name="shipping_timeslot" value="<?php echo $ship_slot_three; ?>" id="evening"/><?php echo $ship_slot_three; ?></br>
                    <input type="radio" name="shipping_timeslot" value="<?php echo $ship_slot_four; ?>" id="night"/><?php echo $ship_slot_four; ?></br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        C:\wamp\www\OC\admin\controller\sale\order.php

        1)
        Find :-
        $this->data['store_url'] = $order_info['store_url'];

        Above that copy and paste :-
        $this->data['shipping_time_slot'] = $order_info['shipping_time_slot'];
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        2)
        Find :- May be line no. 1580
        $this->data['comment'] = nl2br($order_info['comment']);

        Below that copy and paste :-
        $this->data['shipping_time_slot'] = $order_info['shipping_time_slot'];

        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        C:\wamp\www\OC\catalog\controller\checkout\confirm.php

        1)
        Find :-
        $data['comment'] = $this->session->data['comment'];

        Below that copy and paste :-
        $data['shipping_timeslot'] = $this->session->data['shipping_timeslot'];

        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        C:\wamp\www\OC\admin\language\english\sale\order.php

        1)
        Find :-
        $_['text_store_name']                         = 'Store Name:';

        Below that copy and paste :-
        $_['text_time_slot']                           = 'Time Slot:';

        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        C:\wamp\www\OC\admin\view\template\sale\order_info.tpl

        1)
        Find :-
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $text_store_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $store_name; ?></td>
        </tr>

        Below that copy and paste :-

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $text_time_slot; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $shipping_time_slot ?></td>
        </tr>

        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        C:\wamp\www\OC\admin\model\sale\order.php

        1)
        Find :-
        'date_modified'           => $order_query->row['date_modified']

        Below that copy and paste :-
        ,
                                        'shipping_time_slot'           => $order_query->row['shipping_time_slot']

        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                THATS IT
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```